# Kestrel server time zone issue in .NET 6 Web API with EF Core 6 and Swagger UI

Tags: .net, swagger, kestrel

Problem:
I'm experiencing an issue with the Kestrel server time zone in my .NET 6 Web API with EF Core 6 and Swagger UI. The server seems to be 3 hours ahead of Argentina time zone and 4 hours ahead of Venezuela time zone, which indicates that it's in a different time zone. I've tried various solutions to configure the Kestrel server time zone without success.

Environment:

- .NET 6 Web API with EF Core 6 and Swagger UI
- Hosted on Windows with Argentina time zone
- Request header in Swagger UI: "access-control-allow-origin: * content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 date: Fri, 05 May 2023 02:32:41 GMT server: Kestrel x-firefox-spdy: h2"
- Docker-compose produces the same issue even with the container's time set correctly

Attempts:

- Configuring Kestrel in appsettings.json:

  {
  "Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
  "Http": {
  "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
  },
  "Https": {
  "Url": "https://localhost:5001"
  }
  }
  }
  }

  But I couldn't find an option for the time zone.
- Configuring Kestrel in Program.cs:

  var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
  {
  webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
  {
  options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(configureOptions =>
  {
  // HTTPS configuration
  });
  options.AddServerHeader = false;
  options.ListenAnyIP(7032, listenOptions =>
  {
  listenOptions.UseHttps();
  });
  options.ListenAnyIP(5032);
  options.ConfigureTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Local);
  });
  webBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
  {
  // Services configuration
  });
  webBuilder.Configure(app =>
  {
  // Application configuration
  });
  })
  .Build();

  await host.RunAsync();

  And:

  builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
  {
  options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(configureOptions =>
  {
  // HTTPS configuration
  });
  options.AddServerHeader = false;
  options.ListenAnyIP(5000);
  options.ListenAnyIP(5001, listenOptions =>
  {
  listenOptions.UseHttps();
  });
  options.SystemClock = SystemClock.Singleton;
  options.SystemClock.TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
  });

But I couldn't find any option for time zones.

Problem:
I want to be able to configure my Web API, either in Visual Studio 2022 or in my docker-compose with SQL Server 2019, to be in the desired time zone. It's worth noting that my host, Hangfire, and SQL Server 2019 all display the correct time, but my Web API running on Kestrel does not.